# Task Scheduler don't start Task every hour (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, scheduled-tasks, cronjob

I configured a powershell script to grab some reddit rss feed.
So I set the task to run every hour once to grab new feed items. But I can only run/trigger
it manually. It won't start at every even hour. Can you spot a mistake in my settings?

Here the GUI screenshots: (below you will find the exported settings in xml-format)

["Der Vorgang wurde erfolgreich beendet." translates to "The task was successfully finished."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Z2u6.png)

[General-TAB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEOjX.png)

[my one Trigger in Trigger-TAB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwEG5.png)

[Actions-TAB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9Pz6.png)

[Conditions-TAB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXIjk.png)

[Settings-TAB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcBPU.png)

```
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2020-06-30T09:27:22.1341845</Date>
    <Author>GEORODIN-SPC\georo</Author>
    <URI>\reddit</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <Repetition>
        <Interval>PT1H</Interval>
        <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
      </Repetition>
      <StartBoundary>2020-06-29T00:00:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByDay>
        <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
      </ScheduleByDay>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>****************</UserId>
      <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>StopExisting</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>true</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT0S</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>powershell</Command>
      <Arguments>-File C:\temp\redditCSV.ps1</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Windows Version: `Version 10.0.18363 Build 18363`

Comment: For the action, in the program box, just type `powershell` and in the arguments box type `-noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -file "C:\temp\redditCSV.ps1"` and test on that first

Comment: Also, does your .ps1 code use any network drives? If so, you will need to fully qualify them using \\server\folder instead of a local mounted letter like  S:\folder

Comment: no its just local and I will try your 1st suggestion

Comment: When it runs it will be invisible because you've chosen run as Highest Available.

Comment: sadly your suggestion did not work @Nazard 
Mark thank for pointing that out, I checked it actually later as test 
but unfortunately it just wont run automated
the RSS feed has tons of new items but my script doesn't get executed(except manually)

Comment: It DOES get executed but it is invisible.

Comment: Hey Mark this Script of mine has one functionality it appends new feed items to a CSV-file. So why do I have no new feed items in my CSV-File? The last entry is from yesterday 7pm (last manual execute) but it should have run numerous times in between. EDIT: Okay it just go executed once just now, guess the restart did smth

Comment: works now like a charm thank you for your advices